# How can I exclude a declared field in ModelForm in form's subclass?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

In Django, I am trying to derive (subclass) a new form from `ModelForm` form where I would like to remove some fields (or to have only some fields, to be more correct). Of course obvious way would be to do (base form is from `django.contrib.auth.forms`):

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
  class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

But this does not work as it adds/keeps also an `username` field in the resulting form. This field was declared explicitly in `UserChangeForm`. Even adding `username` to `exclude` attribute does not help.

Is there some proper way to exclude it and I am missing something? Is this a bug? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.pop('username')

  class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

This dynamically removes a field from the form when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the (generic) workaround (still missing taking `exclude` into the account) is:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  for field in list(self.fields):
    if field not in self._meta.fields:
      del self.fields[field]
```

But this smells like a bug to me.